# Elements move when pages load and get back to the right position

Tags: html, css

I have some elements of my page that is moving when the pages loads..

Like this one:

```
.letterBar {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #212121;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:0;
    font-weight: lighter;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    padding-left: 0.6px;
    width: 1182px;
}

.letterBar a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 9.4px 16.8px;
    margin: 2px 0px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #d0d0d0;
    background: #191919;
    width: 
}
```

While Loading:
[image: While Loading]

When pages loads:
[image]

I know that the letter is moving down and back to the right position because when loads the width of letterBar is moving too, but how i can fix it??

Comment: Try wrapping their parent in a `display:flex` with the `flex-direction:row`.

Comment: You are experiencing a layout shift due to webfont loading time. You can [read more about it](https://simonhearne.com/2021/layout-shifts-webfonts/). Using `display: flex;` as @Endothermic_Dragon said might help, but you could see this kind of behaviour somewhere else where you couldn't use this trick, so I would suggest to learn more about layout shift.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with display:flex and row!